# Second screen flickering 16.04

Tags: drivers, unity, graphics, multiple-monitors, flicker

My second screen flickers to black every now and then. It seems to be dependent on what is being drawn in it, because if I just have the desktop open, then it won't flicker very much, but if I have a program in it, it will flicker a lot, and if I have a youtube video playing in firefox on that screen, it will flicker so much that it's off about 85% of the time, and it becomes unusable until I can get firefox onto the main screen. I have used 3 graphics cards in my computer since it started: Radeon R7 260X, AMD RX 550, and AMD RX 560. The second screen is in portrait mode, not landscape. The screen works perfectly fine on Windows, so I know it has something to do with my drivers on Linux. I looked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2061180 and it looks most like my problem, except I'm on AMD instead of NVIDIA.

cat /etc/lsb-release outputs

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu 
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04 
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial 
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
```

uname -a outputs

```
Linux [my hostname lol] 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga outputs

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:67ff] (rev cf)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:8a91]
Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

env | grep DESK outputs

```
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh hey i figured it out. Yay. I followed the instructions here: https://www.reddit.com/r/SolusProject/comments/53nvcm/help_screen_flickering_on_rx_480_with_amdgpu_on/?st=jcidz4k7&sh=3ec07c37

This is what it says:
Open up a terminal and run

sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf

A blank document will pop up. Inside, you need to paste in this stuff.

```
Section "Device"

Identifier  "Radeon RX 480"

Driver "amdgpu"

Option "AccelMethod" "glamor"

Option "DRI" "3"

Option "TearFree" "on"

EndSection
```

Why this isn't an automatic setting is beyond me. Ah, Ubuntu. I love you so much.